# Принтер отказывается печатать с ошибкой "out of memory"

Tags: ubuntu, печать

Я иногда вижу эту проблему вот уже в нескольких вериях Ubuntu.
Иногда мой принтер отказывается печатать  pdf и odt файлы с ошибкой "out of memory" (не хватает памяти).
Windows вполне успешно печатает те же файлы на том же принтере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашелся на форуме https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1026859

Эта проблема возникает с лазерными принтерами.
Для того, чтобы напечатать страницу, лазерный принтер сначала превращает ее в огромный bitmap. Теперь ему нужно хранить в памяти одновременно его и оригинальный файл. Поэтому памяти не хватает.
Но можно преобразовать `pdf` в `ps` с помощью команды `pdf2ps` и напечатать преобразованный файл.

У меня все напечаталось, но остался вопрос, почему  Windows справляется и так.

Comment: Драйвер Windows может проводить растеризацию на компьютере. В этом случаем принтер даже не видит исходный файл, на печать отправляется только картинка.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, как-то обидно, что  Windows  справляется, а Ubuntu нет. Увы, по опыту я знаю, что открывть на Ubuntu bug report это пустая трата времени.

Comment: В Windows исторически были сильные драйверы софтверные без обращения к железу принтеров. И производитель принтера был заинтересован в поддержке Windows, а значит работал вместе с Микрософт. В Убунту нет ни того, ни другого.